# Talk back to a device behind firewall over established connection - how?

Tags: .net, tcp

A device behind firewall establishes and maintains a **socket connection** to my server. I talk back to the device over the established connection. What is this pattern called and where could I get more info, .net code examples etc.?

**Background** - our devices have only serial ports and we use GSM modems at customer sites. We then call each modem from our office to retrieve data. The problem is that mobile broadband (GPRS/UMTS etc), especially M2M-one for small amounts of data is cheap. Circuit-switched data (calling modems and faxes) is expensive, in some countries deprecated, unsupported or even unavailable (Thailand). So we are reversing the pattern and using GPRS+TCP socket feature in the modem.

**I have implemented** this in my "automated data retriever" for sending defined packets of data (for example "give me your serial number") and expecting responses to my requests (wait until the whole response has arrived with known byte count and/or known stop sequence).

**What I want to achieve** is something similar to serial port (poll the buffer and read all new bytes) or event model (SendBytes / NewBytesReceived) or maybe something even more modern (Reactive Extensions?).

**My ultimate goal** is a small server, which only does this, allowing several programs to connect to the remote devices. Then I could run a "configuration" application for configuring device 98 and at the same time allow "automatic data retriever" to work with devices 13, 18 and 27.

Bonus question - what name would you give to this server/pattern?

Comment: Socket communication is possible and assuming that the client makes the initial connection, then the firewall should not have an issue so long as the connection is maintained. Searching for `.net Client/Server` might be a good place to start.#

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls are programmed so they forward back to the original device the answer to any tcp connection the device initiated.

The device behind the firewall must always be the one who initiates the connection.

The server is easy, just wait for connections in a pre-defined port, then create a new thread to handle each new incoming connection. That way the server can handle multiple connections at the same time.

Keep in mind that if the connection is idle for a long time, the firewall might lose the association with the original device. You can implement a keep alive mechanism or just close the connection every time your device is going to be idle.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have implemented already. There is a protocol, which allows the devices to detect that a connection is down and reestablish it. I am looking for advice / pointers / code samples to modularize this, allowing it to run as a separate server and providing connectivity for several external programs, and to modernize code, escaping from callback hell and allowing to send and receive a constant stream of bytes, not only request/responses as in current code.

Comment: Additionally, I don't really want to run a thread for each connection - for scalability reasons. I plan to have around 1000 connections, there will be little traffic over each of them, but they will be connected around the clock.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you need to work with a non-blocking tcp api. I don't know much about that. Perhaps you should post a new question focusing on that.